# Oracle SQL: Create a new field based on multiplying 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I think I might be overlooking something obvious here. I'm not asking someone to write the whole code for me, I just need a hint or a link to a similar case, please. I'm posting it without a test case. Thanks in advance.

Here is my table:

```
Select Currency, Amount
from ABC_TABLE
```

Output:

[image]

So *Amount* is the amount by currency, we have these in EUR, USD and GBP. Here is my question:

I need to create a new column lets say *Amount_CNY* that represent each amount, but exchanged to "Yuan (CNY)".
So this "new" column resultant of the existing columns
The thing is each currency has a different exchange rate, as of today:

> For EUR:
>
> 1 EUR: 7,74 Yuan
>
> For USD:
>
> 1 USD : 7 Yuan
>
> For GBP:
>
> 1 GBP: 8,23  Yuan

We keep this information *(7,74; 7; 8,23)* in the table,  FX_RATE is the field. I have tried to use "case when" but  How can I do this, I have tried to use "case" condition, but can't manage to change the amount for each curency.

This is my desired output:

[image]

Comment: Don't use CASE. See: [SQL Joins - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Comment: Please include the entire table in your question.

Comment: `FX_RATE` is the field in same table
OR
It's a field from a different table ?

Comment: Hi, FX_RATE it is the same table

Comment: For Example :
How the `Amount_CNY` is calculated for Currecy `EUR` ;
It's `100 * 0.14 * ?`;
Can you clarify ?I felt something is missing .
I am not able to calculate it manually to match `733,62`
OR May be I am not able to understand

Comment: You are right, my bad, I added the exchange rate the other way around. Now it is corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data from your abc_table you just should get exchange rates or create cte. Join your table to exchange rates and calculate CNY amount:

```sql
WITH
    abc_table AS
        (   Select 'EUR' "CURRENCY", 100 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All 
            Select 'GBP' "CURRENCY", 250 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
            Select 'USD' "CURRENCY", 300 "AMOUNT" From Dual  
        ),
    cny_exchange_rates AS
        (
            Select 'EUR' "CURRENCY", 0.14 "CNY_RATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'USD' "CURRENCY", 0.13 "CNY_RATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'GBP' "CURRENCY", 0.12 "CNY_RATE" From Dual 
        )
Select a.CURRENCY, a.AMOUNT, Round(a.AMOUNT/c.CNY_RATE, 2) "AMOUNT_CNY"
From abc_table a
Inner Join cny_exchange_rates c ON(c.CURRENCY = a.CURRENCY)

CURRENCY     AMOUNT AMOUNT_CNY
-------- ---------- ----------
EUR             100     714.29 
USD             300    2307.69 
GBP             250    2083.33
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.currency,t.amount,fx.*
from ABC_TABLE t
join FX_RATE fx on t.currency=fx.currency
```

As you haven't provided tables structures I can imagine something like above